# Can't Pay Initial $5 Chrome Developer Dashboard Fee

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, chrome-web-store

I've built an extension to Chrome and have loaded it into the developer dashboard, but I get a message that:

> A one-time developer registration fee of US$5.00 is required to verify your account and publish items.

When I click Learn More, it takes me to this [page](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/about_signup?hl=en&gl=US).  But when I click on PayNow, nothing happens.  It just redirects back to the dashboard with the following status:

> This publisher is not linked to a Google Wallet account.

This article talks more about how to pay the [developer registration fee](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/answer/187591), but doesn't offer much by way of advice.

I have a [Google Wallet](https://wallet.google.com/) account, but can't figure out how to  link it with my new developer account.

The same issue was posted recently on [Google Chrome Forum](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/pkmiFvCypks) and I've added it to the [Chromium-Extensions Group](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-extensions/wBvVCdAjU6c), but neither have generated answers yet

Comment: Oh hi there, I'm the person who posted that, it's a small world! From what I can tell, there's a small error in Google's JavaScript that prevents the payment form from popping up correctly (there's an undefined variable). Of course all the JavaScript has been minimized, so there's no realistic way to go in and fix it yourself. If anyone has a solution, I'd really appreciated it!

Comment: Hey there!  I imagine some change to Google Wallet has broken the way their developer dashboard works and they just haven't noticed yet.  I hope it's fixed soon.  I'll post it here if I find anything helpful.

Comment: @pandavenger, what's the URL of the page with the Javascript error?

Comment: @JeffreyYasskin, https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard

Comment: @JeffreyYasskin It's what omab said.

Comment: @KyleMit: You should post an answer rather than putting that information in your question.

Comment: @AlEverett, I guess I view the updated I posted as more of an ongoing process.  I'll conclude with an answer when the issue is resolved.  If I saw this question was answered, I'd expect a resolution, but as of now, there isn't one.

Comment: It's very likely not going to be a good fit here anyway. Since the problem seems to be a bug, there's nothing anyone can suggest as a solution. Once the bug is fixed, no one will have this issue, so it won't be any help to future readers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a bug that only Google can resolve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update: 7/18/13**

Div from Google has posted an [update](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/pkmiFvCypks/fjcZJgpD1iEJ) on the Google Products Forum:

> Hi folks:
>
> Thanks so much for your reports -- we definitely want you to get to publishing! We've been working with the team here and it looks like a fix is on its way (hurray). No exact timeline, but it should be here soon.
>
> More from me if I receive any updates. Thanks again for letting us know!
>
> Cheers,
> Div

**Update: 7/18/13**

Joe Marini from Google has posted the following [update](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/chromium-extensions/wBvVCdAjU6c/nAs673U6URoJ) on the Chrome Extensions Group

> If you are having issues paying the fee, please send me a message.

**Update: 7/19/13**

Div from Google has posted the following [update](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/pkmiFvCypks/fjcZJgpD1iEJ)

> Hi all! Update from me as promised! The fix has been identified -- woohoo! It should roll out fairly soon. I'll be sure to update one more time (and will stop filling your inboxes :) once it's fully live. Thanks for your patience on this.

**Update: 7/19/13**

Joe Marini from Google has posted the following [update](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/chromium-extensions/wBvVCdAjU6c/wMyvxZi1zkQJ) on the Chrome Extensions Group

> The fix has been checked in and will go live with the next CWS release on Monday or Tuesday.

**Update: 7/23/13 - RESOLVED**

Users have [posted](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/pkmiFvCypks/e4yS_gJRG44J) on the forum that the update is working correctly

Comment: It is happening right now. Anyone same as me?